# Pushing a box stuck to the ground at discrete locations

Tags: forces, stress-strain

I have a rigid box. It is stuck to the ground with scotch tape at discrete locations around the box. I would like to determine the forces developed at the scotch tape locations when I push and pull on the box with forces F1 and F2.

Assume I know all the geometric information about this experiment. This would include the length, width and height of the box, the relative location of application of the forces F1 and F2 and locations of the scotch tape.

Assume also that the box and ground are fairly rigid with respect to the scotch tape.

What simple analytical method exists to solve a problem like this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you employ the idea of [virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work).

Using this method, you would assume a small displacement of the box.  Then the force at each piece of tape would be proportional to the displacement at that location.  The total forces in all the pieces of tape will be equal and opposite of the applied forces.

The assumed displacement would be based on your intuition.  For example, perhaps the box will pivot about the lower right edge.

Comment: Wouldn't virtual work require material information about the box ? I'm referring to things like modulus of elasticity, shear modulus and or moment of inertia? I don't really have this information. I just have geometry, force magnitudes and mass (in lbs) of the box.